# How do I Format Linq methods to stack vertically with Resharper?

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

Is there a way in Resharper to format all linq methods to stack up on each other vertically. 
I have some code which look like this:

```
xTable.Include(x => x.RelatedTable.Select(y => y.Childrens)).Include(x => x.SomeField).Where(x => x.Guid == token).ToList();
```

I would like to format the code to look like this:

```
    xTable.Include(x => x.RelatedTable.Select(y => y.Childrens))
          .Include(x => x.SomeField)
          .First(x => x.Guid == token)
          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're after one of these two items in the Options page:

```
Code Editing
  ->C#
    ->FormattingStyle
      ->Other
        -> Align Multiline Constructs
          -> 1) LINQ query
          -> 2) Chained method calls
```